# C++ SQLite3 Bind-Blob Not Working As Expected

Tags: c++, sqlite, blob

I have an image stored in memory as a two dimensional array of unsigned shorts and am able to write the image out to file without issue, I am however trying to save the image as a blob directly to my SQLite database using bind-blob and prepared statements, however following other examples I've seen don't seem to be working for me.

I've created my table successfully using the following query:

CREATE TABLE ImageData (Data Blob)

```
static int imgSize=1000;
static unsigned short *image=new unsigned short[imgSize];
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char *tail;
char * sql = "INSERT INTO SongLoopData (Data) VALUES ( ? )";
sqlite3_open("imageDB.db", &db);

(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL));
sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, image, imgSize*sizeof(unsigned short), SQLITE_STATIC);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I would expect that this would be enough to pass the image into my database, but it doesn't actually pass anything at all and doesn't return any console errors either.  I'm sure I'm doing something silly but am struggling to figure it out myself.

Comment: The length of a blob is its size in bytes. And what are you trying to accomplish with all that funky casting? The third argument of `sqlite3_bind_blob()` is a void pointer...

Comment: Plus you're trying to `COMMIT` without ever beginning a transaction? That'd be an error if you looked for them.

Comment: So I was trying to use the function for passing multiple types through ideally, but regardless it doesn't work even if I change the function parameter to the signed short array and pass that into bind_blob.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of how I could accomplish what I'm trying to do?  i.e. just a simple insert of my raw data from an array of unsigned short?

Comment: `sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, data, bytes_of_data, SQLITE_STATIC);`. *Maybe*. Depends on the layout of the 2d array that `data` points to. If it's not all contiguous memory things become more involved.

Comment: So that doesn't seem to be working unfortunately.  The array is continuous, I've updated my question to hopefully give a slightly better idea of what I'm working with.

Comment: That call to bind looks right now. But where are you actually executing the statement?

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot, that was it.  Thanks for your help, can't believe I missed something so simple.